# careers 2.0 should also have my ui.stackexchange.com account

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I like the new Stack Exchange careers 2.0 site but why is my ui.stackexchange.com stack exchange account not in my profile?

Answer (score 8):

Rup is correct.  We exclude per-site metas (except meta.stackoverflow.com) and beta sites from your network accounts list.

**THIS JUST IN**

After a careers team hallway meeting we're going to change this to allow you to add public beta sites and answers to the StackExchange Network section of your profile.  Will be in later this week.

Comment: Excellent ... and fast!

Comment: Update: This should be in later _this_ week...

Comment: Update:  Complete.

Answer (score 3):

It's because at the moment careers only lists fully-graduated sites and ui.stackexchange is still in beta.

It might make sense to allow you to show beta sites with a higher rep threshold, though, or if you're a mod on one.